# Render the content and open in new window which should inherit from same layout using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a layout page which renders the body and refers to angular js and css.
    I have Index page which has 3 tabs. To render tab body, i am using ng-include.
    Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0fGcwb0HUR6xbsOhFa4I?p=info) which has index page.

On click of one button in first tab i want to open new window in which i need to render html content. But, I want to render the content in same layout with same angular controller.
But it is not rendering.
Please find the below ResultsView.html page which i am trying to open.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<div id="docFormatContent" ng-show="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="border:1px solid #B1B4B5;">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary center-block" ng-model="PrintBtn" ng-click="printDocument()">Print</md-button>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="panel-body" style="width:100%; overflow:auto; height:100%" id="docFormatContent">
        </div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And Js code:

$('#docFormatContent').html(data.docFormat);
                $window.open('../AngularJS/views/ResultsView.html', 'Cpage');

Let me know if you need any more information on the same.